# Extroverts vs introverts - user profile design considerations?

Tags: user-behavior

When speaking with a person who is more reserved, quiet, or shy in nature I need to ask more generic questions in order to make them feel comfortable and open to respond.

When having a conversation with someone who is more open and willing to share, on the other hand, I need to ask questions that are laser focused in order to have a meaningful conversation.

This made me wonder if there are any design choices that accommodate both personality types equally well or ways to adjust an interface to accommodate both introverts and extroverts?

Specifically when getting a user to fill out their user profile will adding a pop-up with the message `"Add a picture of your lovely face to your profile so all your friends can see your beautiful smile!"` make shy users more likely to hit the cancel button?

Is there data showing that adding more emotion and excitement to a user interface engages introverts more or less than extroverts or does personality type not matter in design?

Comment: This is a bit broad can you narrow the design question down to a certain type of interaction you are designing for? There are too many facets right now for this to be answerable.

Comment: I don't see a correlation between having conversations with people in person and UI design for said people.

Comment: welcome to the forum.  i like this question but it is too broad to answer could you give a few specific examples of a user interaction that would make you assume one personality type over the other?

Comment: I tried to make the question answerable and will see if I can find any data specific to personality types...

Comment: I couldn't really find much data on this topic so I'm voting to close it but perhaps this article will be interesting for you  --  http://www.uie.com/articles/multiple_personalities/  --  it is more about how the same user can exhibit such different personality types depending on the application.

Comment: Okay thanks anyway.  I'll try not to ask very general questions in the future

Comment: I've never seen an introvert/extrovert psychographic split so I found this question thought provoking. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think even extroverts would find that prompt weird/corny and that the site is ultimately weird/corny/creepy.

The thing is, you want to cater to a general audience, so wording or coloring to suit one temperament can mean you'll lose others. So, don't design to particular personalities unless you actually want to weed out those who are not that particular personality.

Design to convey your site's message and purpose.

Comment: Good point about only targeting a specific type of user in the case you want to weed out the other type of users like a site trying to get applicants for a stage performance can get away with asking more creative questions.